# adding items in the second column of listview control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a list view iam using to view files in my disk drive, in this list i want to make the first column as checkbox and the second column as the items of the list view, so that i can double click any item in the second column to inter the folder iam clicking.
is that possible? and how can i do it?

thanks in advance

Comment: i have done the things that hamad told me but it is not what i want, what is adding item in the subitem,add() method. this item contains name key and image and text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checked list items set

```
this.ListView1.CheckBoxes = true;
```

In order to handle the double click, you should register the double click event of the list view

```
this.listView1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_DoubleClick);

private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something ...
}
```